# Kmemcheck output location

Tags: linux, memory-management, memory-leaks, linux-kernel

I have configured and installed a kernel with kemecheck enabled.
I would like to know if a wrong memory access has occurred where can the output of kmemcheck be viewed from?

Answer (score 0):

When `kmemcheck` encounter a problem, it prints information about it into the kernel log. You may read this log using `dmesg`.